# SQL Server import row string to table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing the following text per row

```
"[0,0,0,1,2,4,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,847,18207,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"
```

Now i want to insert these 28 values in a table containing 28 **columns**. I tried a few split functions but these would return only rows.

Any ideas?

Comment: SQL Server has no concept of "string array".  How is the data actually stored?

Comment: use a split function and then dynamically pivot it's results.

Comment: is it always fixed 28 values into 28 columns ?

Comment: always 28 values -- destination table actually has 30 columns - 28 for the values, one key column, one other column. Value / column amount will not change.

Comment: select "insert into table28 values(" + SUBSTRING(text, 2, LEN(text) -2) + ");" as "sql" from table, run, copy column, paste and run :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using [dbo.fnParseString()](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=76033)

```
INSERT INTO a_table (col1, col2, col3, . . . )
SELECT dbo.fnParseString(-1, ',', str)
      ,dbo.fnParseString(-2, ',', str)
      ,dbo.fnParseString(-3, ',', str)
      ,....
FROM  yourtable
```

Comment: I agree that a splitter is a good approach but the splitter you referenced is horribly inefficient. You do NOT need to resort to looping for splitting strings. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings or here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: those splits CSV into rows. OP required it in column

Comment: Right. But you don't need a loop for that. You can use crosstab or pivot to get them back into columns. This would be a great time for an xml splitter.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @x XML

;with cte as (
SELECT '[0,0,0,1,2,4,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,847,18207,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]' as col
)

SELECT @x= (
SELECT CAST('<s>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col,'[','<a>'),']','</a>'),',','</a><a>') +'</s>'AS XML)
FROM cte
FOR XML PATH('')
)


SELECT  t.v.value('a[1]','int'),
        t.v.value('a[2]','int'),
        t.v.value('a[3]','int'),
        ...
        t.v.value('a[28]','int')
FROM @x.nodes('/s') as t(v)
```